# Double loop (loop inside a loop) vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA, and am in need of some help to fully understand some issues.

I have a [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5yy0siWjtBSRGZoYWxaZVRkcDQ) with many sheets, and am in need to make a copy of the file for every team. Each file must not have the information of other teams.

I have managed to assemble this code that seems to work for one sheet, but not for every sheet that I need.

The first four sheets are supposed to remain unchanged (no filtering in these ones) and the sheet in yellow is a different arrangement from the others (I need to look at this later) but the remaining sheets have exactly the same construction, so the column to do "the math" is the same. (file in attachment with example)

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()

'lobs names
Dim lob(14) As String

lob(0) = "AV"
lob(1) = "CA"
lob(2) = "G_13"
lob(3) = "HSTP"
lob(4) = "JLS"
lob(5) = "JR"
lob(6) = "LPV"
lob(7) = "MAO"
lob(8) = "NML"
lob(9) = "PRJ"
lob(10) = "RB"
lob(11) = "RG"
lob(12) = "SPN"
lob(13) = "VE"

'counter
Dim i As Integer

'numbers of rows
Dim rowtotest As Long

' to create a copy of the template to be filled'
Dim sFile As String 'Source file - Template'
Dim sDFile As String 'Destination file - Template'
Dim sSFolder As String 'Source folder  - Template'
Dim sDFolder As String 'Destination Folder'

sSFolder = "C:\Users\Pacosta\Desktop\ParaIndividuals\team.xlsx"

MsgBox (sSFolder)

'Destination Path Window selector
Dim destinationWindow As FileDialog
Set destinationWindow = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
destinationWindow.Title = "Select Destination Folder"

'only select one folder
destinationWindow.AllowMultiSelect = False
If destinationWindow.Show Then
sDFolder = destinationWindow.SelectedItems(1) + "\"
End If

'copy cell content to excel file based on template with bookmarks'
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

For i = 0 To 14
'create a file with same name as lob
sDFile = lob(i) + ".xlsx"

'Create object excel document'
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Copy the template do destination'
FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder + sFile), sDFolder + sDFile, True
Next i

Dim file As String

For i = 0 To 11
file = sDFolder + lob(i) + ".xlsx"
Call GetIndices(lob(i), file)
Next i

 End Sub

'delete rows diferents from lobs namefile
Sub DeleteRows(lob As String, file As String)

'disable automatic calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'count number of rows
Dim rowtotest As Long

'variable to work with all files
Dim ficheiro As Workbook
Set ficheiro = Workbooks.Open(file)

With ficheiro.Sheets(1)

'delete rows of the other lob's
For rowtotest = .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1 To 5 Step -1
If StrComp(.Cells(rowtotest, 7).Value, lob) <> 0 Then
    .Rows(rowtotest).Delete
End If
Next rowtotest 
End With

' Force a calculation
Application.Calculate

' Then remember to run automatic calculations back on
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

'save file
ficheiro.Save

'close file
ficheiro.Close

End Sub

Sub GetIndices(lob As String, file As String)

'count number of rows
Dim rowtotest As Long

'primeiro indice
 Dim indice1 As Integer

 'segundo indice
Dim indice2 As Integer

'variable to work with all files
Dim ficheiro As Workbook
Set ficheiro = Workbooks.Open(file)

With ficheiro.Sheets(1)

'delete rows of the other lob's
For rowtotest = .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row + 1 To 5 Step -1
  If StrComp(.Cells(rowtotest, 8).Value, lob) = 0 Then
    indice2 = rowtotest
    rowtotest = 0
   End If
Next rowtotest

'delete rows of the other lob's
For rowtotest = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row + 1 Step 1
 If StrComp(.Cells(rowtotest, 8).Value, lob) = 0 Then
    indice1 = rowtotest
    rowtotest = 1000
  End If
Next rowtotest

Dim texto As String
texto = indice2 & ":" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Rows(texto).Delete

texto = 5 & ":" & indice1
.Rows(texto).Delete

ficheiro.Save
ficheiro.Close

End With

End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to put the code that i already achived:

Comment: You should edit your code into this post rather than a restricted, offsite sheet. Also, are you doing this in Excel, or in Google Drive? VBA only works in Excel.

Comment: Thaks for the quick reply, i am doing it in excel, just whated to show how the organization of the excel is. code edited

Comment: It looks like my grammar edit overrode your code edit (Not sure why it was approved). Try editing your code back in one more time.

Comment: done ,sorry but it is my first post...

Comment: No problem, welcome to the site.

Comment: cant realy fully understand, i built the code from bits and pieces i found in this site, and try to mold it to my needs... realy a newb trying to learn :)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you can shorten the code a bit by declaring `lob` to be `Variant` then using the line `lob = Array("AV","CA","G_13","HSTP","JLS","JR","LPV","MAO","NML","PRJ","RB","RG","SPN","VE")`

Comment: I don't think it answers either, but I noticed some holes where things can go not quite like you want.  In some lines, you use `With` correctly, but not in each case, i.e. `rowtotest = .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1 To 5 Step -1`  You also need to add the `.`before `Rows`.

Comment: i notice as well, that you only ever working with the first worksheet. sounds like you want to loop through all the sheets. Actually, I would say you will be better served to post only the code that is not doing what you expect and be more specific with what you want a certain piece of code to do. Have you stepped through your code line-by-line and tested the expected results? I say this because the amount of code is simply too much to go through and try to modify for you ... That said, I think you need to loop through the worksheets in the `GetIndices` sub.

Comment: The problem is that I want to replicate the action that I am accomplishing with this code to all the sheets of the workbook except the first 4, but I am not sure how I can accomplish that, neither where to put the code (even if i knew what it was...)